# Как будет быстрее? java

Tags: java

Есть ли разница при создании в скорости между этим кодами

```
int a;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    a = sc.nextInt();
  }
```

и

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
  int  a = sc.nextInt();
  }
```

В цикле допустим я сравниваю с чем-нибудь. Т.е. я же перезаписываю каждый раз переменную в первом случае, а во втором я создаю новую? Влияет ли как-то на память\скорость?
P.S. нужно знать для решения олимпиадных задач.

Comment: При решении олимпиадных задач вы должны полагаться на правильные алгоритмы, а не на странные микрооптимизации. Даже если какая-то версия оптимизатора делает один из двух семантически одинаковых вариантов быстрее, выигрыш в несколько наносекунд вам ничего не даст.

Comment: Нормальный компилятор увидит, что результат метода не используется и совсем выбросит цикл.

Comment: Если вам нужна скорость ввода-вывода пишите олимпиады на С/С++. Зря что ли на Java раньше TL был в 1.5 раза больше. А ввод/вывод медленее раз в 5...

Comment: @VladD вы конечно правы, но методом "Четырёх русских" иногда задачи проламывали жёстко... Там буквально молились правильно кешу и компиятору)

Comment: Все высокоуровневые языки обладают оптимизаторами, которые оптимизируют код во время компиляции. Вы даже не узнаете что на самом деле происходит с вашей переменной пока не залезете в бинарник и не прочтете его!

Comment: @pavel: А что за метод?

Comment: Статический компилятор и, в особенности, JIT-компилятор Java сейчас используют настолько агрессивные спекулятивные оптимизации, что думать о подобных ручных "оптимизациях" становится бессмысленно. Оптимизатор JIT-компилятора благодаря подробнейшей "живой" статистике о вашем коде запросто может обгонять по эффективности оптимизатор С/С++, который строит предположения только по исходному код.

Answer (score 10):

[Вот хороший пример](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-noaccent/#N101AB)

> Не выносите переменные из циклов
>
> Часто встречается ситуация, когда объявление переменных выносится за границы циклов. Такая ситуация чревата ошибками, поскольку к переменным возможен доступ вне той
>   области, в которой задумывалось их применение. Это особенно вероятно
>   для переменных с часто встречающимися именами, например i или tmp. В
>   частности, старые значения могут сохраниться в переменных и нарушить
>   работу последующего кода самым непредсказуемым образом.
>
> Студенты, отличающиеся чрезмерной склонностью к оптимизации, могут возразить,
>   что это снизит производительность кода, поскольку больше действий
>   придется выполнять на каждой итерации цикла. Однако лишнее объявление
>   переменной не требует выполнения никаких инструкций. Перенос
>   объявления внутрь цикла никак не скажется на производительности
>   приложения, выполняющегося на платформе Java.

Comment: Спасибо, самый внятный ответ.

Comment: Ключевое слово в ответе — «студенты».

Answer (score 6):

В данном случае имеет смысл посмотреть, как в обоих случаях выглядит код после компиляции.

Java код:

```
int x = 10;
Random sc = new Random();
int a;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Часть байт кода выполняющая инструкции `a = sc.nextInt();System.out.println(a);`:

```
LINENUMBER 14 L5
 ALOAD 2
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/util/Random.nextInt ()I
 ISTORE 3
L6
 LINENUMBER 15 L6
 GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 ILOAD 3
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (I)V
```

Инструкции `ISTORE 3` и `ILOAD 3` представляют собой работу с локальной переменной `а`.

Java код:

```
int x = 10;
Random sc = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    int  a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Часть байт кода выполняющая инструкции `int  a = sc.nextInt(); System.out.println(a);`:

```
LINENUMBER 13 L5
 ALOAD 2
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/util/Random.nextInt ()I
 ISTORE 4
L6
 LINENUMBER 14 L6
 GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 ILOAD 4
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (I)V
```

Инструкции `ISTORE 4` и `ILOAD 4` представляют собой работу с локальной переменной `а`.

Про локальные переменные в jvm можно почитать [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1).  Из приведенного выше кода видно, что в обоих случаях мы получаем идентичный байт-код, значит и памяти используется в первом случае столько же, как и во втором и скорость работы будет одинакова.

Answer (score 0):

Можно самому измерить скорость выполнения кода и понять какой быстрее :
`long s1 = new Date().getLong();`
`код`
`long s2 = new Date().getLong();`
`long res=s2-s1;`

Comment: good luck with that! что вы будете делать, если затраты на создание Date будут больше самого измеряемого кода? как вы будете мерять погрешность?

Comment: разве затраты не будут равны с обеих измерений? 
Суть то в том что бы увидеть разницу, а не замерить конкретный пример. А разница остается одинаковой в любом случае