# Создание строки в цикле и оптимизация кода

Tags: java, строки, оптимизация

Как будет правильнее (и займёт меньше времени при выполнении), если на каждой итерации цикла создаётся новая строка?

**1 вариант** - создание объекта строки в цикле:

```
while (conn.hasNext()) {
    String timerStr = StringUtils.isBlank(conn.getString("time_field")) ? "time" : conn.getString("time_field"));
    report.setTimer(new TimerSystem(id, timerStr));
}
```

**2 вариант** - вынос создания строки за цикл:

```
String timerStr;
while (conn.hasNext()) {
    timerStr = StringUtils.isBlank(conn.getString("time_field")) ? "time" : conn.getString("time_field"));
    report.setTimer(new TimerSystem(id, timerStr));
}
```

**3 вариант** - без объявления переменной String:

```
while (conn.hasNext()) {
    report.setTimer(new TimerSystem(id, StringUtils.isBlank(conn.getString("time_field")) ? "time" : conn.getString("time_field"))));
}
```

Или же все эти варианты абсолютно равнозначны?

*P.S.* На сайте уже был похожий вопрос [Как будет быстрее? java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549896/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5-java/549923#549923), но мне всё-таки кажется, что здесь работа со строками и примитивными типами может отличаться.

Comment: а где в примерах конкатенация строк?

Comment: @Grundy, так ведь вопрос не про конкатенацию, а про создание новой строки.

Comment: Да, я не совсем верно понял вопрос. 1 и 3 варианты равнозначны, если переменная _timerStr_ не используется вне цикла, то и 2 так же. Для проверки можно посмотреть генерируемый байткод

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд, оптимизировать в приведенных вариантах нечего. Переменная `timerStr` - это всего лишь указатель на строку. Cтрого говоря, сама аллокация памяти и создание новой строки у вас совершенно в другом месте, это зависит от реализации функции `conn.getString()`. Внутри цикла вы работаете только с указателями на строки.

Я бы записал в более удобочитаемом виде и не беспокоился о производительности до того момента пока вы не поймете, что именно это место является узким и требует оптимизаций:

```
while (conn.hasNext()) {
    String timeField = conn.getString("time_field");
    String timerStr = StringUtils.isBlank(timeField) ? "time" : timeField;
    report.setTimer(new TimerSystem(id, timerStr));
}
```

---

Дополнительно можно прочитать про [string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings).